# Connecting to a gRPC service through kubernetes nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, grpc, rancher, grpc-java

I deployed a gRPC service (spring boot docker image) in my on-premise kubernetes cluster. I followed this [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/grpc) to configure correctly deployment, service and ingress kubernetes manifests.

I tried to test my service using grpcurl :

```
grpcurl -insecure fortune-teller.mydomain.cloud:443 build.stack.fortune.FortuneTeller/Predict
```

and the request still stuck for minutes.

In the ingress logs (debug enabled), I see client timeout :

```
client timed out (110: Connection timed out), client: 1.2.3.4, server: _, request: "POST /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo HTTP/2.0", host: "fortune-teller.mydomain.cloud:443"
```

After 4 timeouts in the ingress logs, the command ends at the client side with :

```
Error invoking method "build.stack.fortune.FortuneTeller/Predict": failed to query for service descriptor "build.stack.fortune.FortuneTeller": rpc error: code = Internal desc = stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I use `nginx/1.13.12` with `rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:0.16.2-rancher1` image.

At the annotation level, I tested :

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
```

and

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"
```

and both have the same result (timeout).

**Note** : I bypassed the ingress testing another gRPC service directly using the kubernetes service DNS and it works.

Any idea of what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a problem in my ingress resource.

Despite the `tls` configuration, the nginx config didn't listen on 443. Something wrong with my `secret`

I fixed this and I retested my different configuration.

The working annotations are :

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"
```

Which are not the annotations used in the kubernetes [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/grpc).

Comment: Where did you get the annotation `grpc-backend` from ?. I tried it and it didn't work